# fit line is too condensed on x-axis (matplotlib, lmfit)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm using `lmfit` to generate a line of best fit for data in the following dataframe:

```
   foci_red   fold_dil
0   0.986947      20.0
1   0.947788      60.0
2   0.908629     180.0
3   0.765047     540.0
4   0.660624    1620.0
5   0.216824    4860.0
6   0.060189   14580.0
7   0.112400   43740.0
8  -0.148658  131220.0
9  -0.070341  393660.0
10  0.960841      20.0
11  0.869471      60.0
12  0.830312     180.0
13  0.673677     540.0
14  0.490935    1620.0
15  0.373459    4860.0
16 -0.005076   14580.0
17  0.047136   43740.0
18  0.138506  131220.0
19 -0.096447  393660.0
20  0.960841      20.0
21  0.869471      60.0
22  0.895577     180.0
23  0.738941     540.0
24  0.321247    1620.0
25  0.334300    4860.0
26  0.086294   14580.0
27  0.060189   43740.0
28 -0.109500  131220.0
29  0.086294  393660.0`
```

With the following function:

```
def func(x, u, s, l, i): 
    return ((l-u)/(1.0+((x/i)**s))) + u
```

And by setting the following parameters:

```
init_model = lmfit.Model(func)
#set initial values
    #from Results.rmd: 
        #Theta1 (upper): 1
        #Theta2 (IC50/EC50): NA
        #Theta3 (Slope): -1
        #Theta4 (lower): 0

params_pog = init_model.make_params()
params_pog.add('u', value=1, min=0.95, max=1.05)
params_pog.add('i', value=50, min=-np.inf, max=np.inf)
params_pog.add('s', value=-1, min=-1.3, max=-0.7)
params_pog.add('l', value=0, min=-0.05, max=0.05)`
```

The result:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = Nelder-Mead
    # function evals   = 790
    # data points      = 30
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.18783349
    reduced chi-square = 0.00722437
    Akaike info crit   = -144.201903
    Bayesian info crit = -138.597114
    R-squared          = 0.96014230
  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
    this fitting method does not natively calculate uncertainties
    and numdifftools is not installed for lmfit to do this. Use
    `pip install numdifftools` for lmfit to estimate uncertainties
    with this fitting method.
[[Variables]]
    u:  0.96936837 (init = 1)
    s: -0.88999854 (init = -1)
    l: -0.03939795 (init = 0)
    i:  1952.96706 (init = 50)
```

Plotting this result against raw data shows a curve that's weirdly condensed on the x-axis:

```
plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook', 'grid'])

fig1 = plt.figure()
fig1, ax = plt.subplots(2)

axes = ax[0]
axes.set_xscale('log')

axes.scatter(janfd, janfr)
axes.plot(func(janfd, 0.96936837, -0.88999854, -0.03939795, 1952.96706), scalex=True)
```

[image: The strange line]

I expected the plot of the curve to span the raw data points, and not be as condensed. Considering a somewhat high r-squared value and parameters that are similar to those of previous fits, I'm not sure what to do.

Am I plotting the curve incorrectly? Is there something messed up with the scaling of the x-axis?

I'm new to python and even newer to its data analysis tools, and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the latest plot command you forgot to pass the x-values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were plotting -- it is always recommended to include a complete, minimal script.  Otherwise, we don't know what your variables mean or what you are doing.

I suggest trying this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit import Model

dat = np.loadtxt('xdat.txt')
x = dat[:, 2]
y = dat[:, 1]

def func(x, u, s, l, i):
    return u + (l-u)/(1.0+((x/i)**s))

fmodel = Model(func)

params = fmodel.make_params(u=1, i=50, s=-1, l=0.00)
params['i'].min=0

result = fmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'ro', label='fit')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which prints out

```
[[Model]]
    Model(func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 67
    # data points      = 30
    # variables        = 4
    chi-square         = 0.18783328
    reduced chi-square = 0.00722436
    Akaike info crit   = -144.201937
    Bayesian info crit = -138.597147
    R-squared          = 0.96014235
[[Variables]]
    u:  0.96936846 +/- 0.04690950 (4.84%) (init = 1)
    s: -0.88999819 +/- 0.16238114 (18.25%) (init = -1)
    l: -0.03939805 +/- 0.03933531 (99.84%) (init = 0)
    i:  1952.96706 +/- 410.661871 (21.03%) (init = 50)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(u, s) = 0.694
    C(s, l) = -0.652
    C(u, i) = -0.517
    C(l, i) = -0.364
    C(u, l) = -0.347
    C(s, i) = -0.105
```

and produces a plot of:
[image]

A couple of points: 1) don't add bounds unless you really need them -- Having `i>0` is needed, otherwise `(x/i)**s` becomes NaN. 2) using the default fitting method notice that it needs 10x fewer functions and gives uncertainties.